# Find largest Max list in an array

Tags: c++

I need to find the first Max list of an array and find it's middle. In other words, having for example this array {2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8, 8} I need to have as a result the index 3, which is the middle of the first max list. I did try but my C++ code is still missing something. Can you please help.
Thanks

The following code is just a sample what I'm working on is an 90 elements array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    int array[] = {2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 0};
    int Max = 0;
    int StartMax = 0, EndMax = 0;

    for (int m = 0 ; m < 9 ; m++){

        if(array[m] > Max){
            Max = array[m];
            StartMax = m;
            EndMax = m;
            cout << "array[m] > Max " << Max << endl;
        }

        else if(array[m] < Max){
            cout << "array[m] < Max " << Max << endl;
        }

        else { 
            int a = array[m] - array[m-1];
            cout << "a = " << a << endl;

            if (a == 0){ 
                cout << "a = " << a << endl;
                EndMax = m;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Index of Max : " << ((StartMax+EndMax)/2) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: What is a "max list"? And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: what is " first Max list"

Comment: It looks exactly as you describe. http://ideone.com/NL7qen

Comment: Are you looking for the *first* or *largest* max list ?

Comment: the code in this link is mine i guess since I am using an online compiler!!

Comment: first Max list means finding the first maximum value in the table not the second. for example {2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 8} here, the four eights is the max first list.

Comment: You should then change your title accordingly to this. Title says find largest max list... This is different.

Comment: ***the code in this link is mine i guess since I am using an online compiler!!*** I copied your code from here and pasted to ideone. My point was your code does exactly as you described 5 hours ago so no changes need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

Your code work for this example but it won't work when you have a second "max list" which has more than 2 elements.

Indeed with `array[] = {2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8};`  (notice the last 8)
We get the result : `middle=4` instead of `middle3` because you enter this branch condition when you encounter `8` again :

```
else { 
   int a = array[m] - array[m-1];
```

And you enter the branch `if (a==0)` and you set `EndMax` to the end of the array !
`StartMax = 1` and `Endmax = 8` thus `middle = 4`
This is not what you want !

[Live Code](http://ideone.com/i954QN)

## Solution

I would suggest to use a boolean tracker to manage that instead :

```
size_t give_middle_max_list(const std::vector<int>& v) {
    size_t idx_start_max = 0;
    size_t idx_end_max = 0;
    int max_val = v[0];
    bool should_continue = false;

    for(size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i ++) {
        if(v[i] > max_val) {
            max_val = v[i];
            idx_start_max = i;
            idx_end_max = i;
            should_continue = true;
        }
        else {
            if (v[i] == max_val && should_continue == true) {
                idx_end_max = i;   // I am still in the first max list 
            }
            else {
                should_continue = false; // I am not in the first max list anymore !
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << idx_start_max << ";" << idx_end_max << std::endl;
    return (idx_end_max + idx_start_max) / 2;
}
```

**[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/127e4c79652afe52)**

Comment: @fjardon Yes I am confused now I quote OP :  `I need to find the first Max list of an array and find it's middle`. OP what do you want ?